# Android studio is not showing any errors but my logcat shows that there are errors

Tags: forceclose

this is my logcat-

03-23 21:02:12.573  22442-22442/the.falacermusicE/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {the.falacermusic/the.falacermusic.ui.activities.HomeActivity} did not call through to super.onStart()
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5196)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.w(TAG, "Started");


    }

Answer (score 0):

> 03-23 21:02:12.573 22442-22442/the.falacermusicE/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {the.falacermusic/the.falacermusic.ui.activities.HomeActivity} did not call through to super.onStart()

As the error states you are implementing the `onStart` method in your `HomeActivity` but you are not going throgh the `super.onStart()` method.